# Loading Content Sequentially Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

TJ Crowder's code from this question ([jQuery load content sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653202/jquery-load-content-sequentially)) is what I am basing this off, but for some reason it is not working as I'd expect.

How I am reading it, it should load the page and have 4 divs that show essentially:

Panel 1
Panel 2
Panel 3
Panel 4

Then, it should sequentially, one after the other load the URL from data-page attribute and replace the "Panel X" with what it is pulling from the URL for that data-page.

I am going to be using this for some charts that take awhile to load, so I wrote a "test" page on my website (the test.php file), that literally waits 5 seconds, then displays a random number and some of Aesop's fables for now to simulate a delay then dumping some text.

If you go to the test file it works fine, but it is not loading it from the code from TJ. Am I missing something?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel" data-page="http://jamesorr.com/test.php">Panel 1</div>
  <div class="panel" data-page="http://jamesorr.com/test.php">Panel 2</div>
  <div class="panel" data-page="http://jamesorr.com/test.php">Panel 3</div>
  <div class="panel" data-page="http://jamesorr.com/test.php">Panel 4</div>
  <script>
    // Assumes script is at the bottom of the page, just before </body>
    (function() {
      var index = 0,
        panels = $(".panel");

      triggerLoad();

      function triggerLoad() {
        var panel;

        if (index <= panels.length) {
          panel = $(panels[index]);
          ++index;
          panel.load(panel.attr("data-page"), triggerLoad);
        }
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

So, based on some of the comments below I am trying it on my own domain in the WordPress plugin I was going to be using it in.

It still does not seem to be working for me there either.

I thought maybe it was the path to the "test.php" file so I've even tried to test several locations and it is still not working:

```
    $Content .= "<h2>Bigger Test</h2>\n\n"; 
$Content .= "<div class=\"panel\" data-page=\"test.php\">Panel 1</div>\n";
$Content .= "<div class=\"panel\" data-page=\"./test.php\">Panel 1</div>\n";
$Content .= "<div class=\"panel\" data-page=\"../test.php\">Panel 1</div>\n";
$Content .= "<div class=\"panel\" data-page=\"../../test.php\">Panel 1</div>\n";
$Content .= "<div class=\"panel\" data-page=\"../../../test.php\">Panel 1</div>\n";
$Content .= "<div class=\"panel\" data-page=\"../../../../test.php\">Panel 1</div>\n";
$Content .= "<div class=\"panel\" data-page=\"../../../../../test.php\">Panel 1</div>\n";

$Content .= "<h2>Part 2 of Bigger Test</h2>\n\n"; 
$Content .= "<div class=\"panel\" data-page=\"./test.php\">Panel 2</div>\n";

$Content .= "<h2>Part 3 of Bigger Test</h2>\n\n"; 
$Content .= "<div class=\"panel\" data-page=\"test.php\">Panel 3</div>\n";

$Content .= "<h2>Part 4 (Final) of Bigger Test</h2>\n\n"; 
$Content .= "<div class=\"panel\" data-page=\"http://jamesorr.com/wp-content/plugins/realestatedata/test.php\">Panel 4</div>\n";

$Content .= <<< EOT
<script>
// Assumes script is at the bottom of the page, just before </body>
(function() {
    var index = 0,
        panels = $(".panel");

    triggerLoad();

    function triggerLoad() {
        var panel;

        if (index <= panels.length) {
            panel = $(panels[index]);
            ++index;
            panel.load(panel.attr("data-page"), triggerLoad);
        }
    }
})();
</script>
EOT;
```

Still does not show the expected content of test.php output file in any of the divs.

Comment: Does "literally waits 5 seconds" differ from "waits 5 seconds"?

Comment: In this case it was to show that it: sleep(5);

Comment: The "Run code snippet" won't work as it's running in a different domain than yours and jQuery's load function uses Ajax, which will be blocked for cross domain requests. Just tried on your site, $("body").load("http://jamesorr.com/test.php") on debugger console works fine, it fills up the body with loaded content.

Comment: If you run your test page on a different domain, then you will see "'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" errors in your console. http://jsfiddle.net/cjs22qn6/

Answer (score 0):

If `http://jamesorr.com/test.php` is a cross domain request, jquery `load` will not work due to security reason. But it should work if it's a same origin request. Optimize your code as `triggerLoad()` is getting executed more than expect (5 times instead of 4 times).

```
if (index < panels.length) {
        panel = $(panels[index]);
        ++index;
        panel.load(panel.attr("data-page"), triggerLoad);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sudipta. I did replace the <= with just <. It is still not working on my own domain and still not sure why.